# Google Compute have used CDN?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cdn, google-compute-engine, google-cdn

I already used Google Compute instance, and it's located us-central.

I'm living Taiwan, ping the instance than average time 180~210ms.

Amazon EC2 located Singapore, average time 70~80ms.

I think this difference latency result, depend your server located, right?

So I guessed Google Compute Engine doesn't support CDN, right?

even Amazon ec2 also the same.

Kind Regards,

PinLiang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Compute runs code while a CDN delivers content (**C**ontent **D**elivery **N**etwork) so they aren't the same thing.  If you get better latency to Amazon EC2 then use that instead but be aware that Google Compute and EC2 work very differently and you wont be able to run the same code on both.

If you want low latency (to Taiwan) compute resources you might want to consider using a Compute Engine instances in the [Asia zones](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/zones#available), see: [4/14/2014 - Google Cloud Platform expands to Asia](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/04/google-cloud-platform-expands-to-asia-pacific.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, location and network connectivity will determine your latency. This is not always obvious though. Submarine cables tend to take particular paths. In some cases a geographically closer location may have higher latency.

A CDN is generally used for distributing static files, at lower latency to more users. Cloudfront can use any site as a custom origin.